# Angular-cli with any other server

Tags: python, flask, angular, angular-cli

I'm relatively new to Angular 2, and I'm trying to build an app using the angular-cli system. This works and I can ng-serve and the application comes up. However, it seems like a huge pain in the ass to try and serve the application with anything other than the ng-serve system. In particular I'm trying to serve the application built with angular-cli with a Python Flask app. The amount of hoops I'm seemingly having to jump through trying to get this to work is making me crazy! I want to do this because I want to serve a REST API with the Python/Flask app that will respond to the HTTP services requests from the Angular 2 application.

Here are the relevant versions I'm using:

```
node - 6.2.2
npm - 2.9.5
angular 2 - rc.4
angular-cli - 1.0.0-beta.9
python - 2.7.5
flask - 0.10.1
```

How can I serve an Angular app while using Flask?

Answer (score 4):

I've actually sort of solved the problem. I have a directory named "smoke" (short for smoke and mirrors ), and inside there I ran the angular-cli command:

```
ng new static
```

This created the angular-cli start out application in the static directory. Then I created this (simplified) Python Flask application:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, redirect
from flask.ext.restful import Api
from gevent import monkey, pywsgi
monkey.patch_all()

def create_app():
    app = Flask("press_controller")

    # map the root folder to index.html
    @app.route("/")
    def home():
        return redirect("/index.html")

    @app.route("/<path:path>")
    def root(path):
        """
        This is the cheesy way I figured out to serve the Angular2 app created
        by the angular-cli system. It essentially serves everything from
        static/dist (the distribution directory created by angular-cli)
        """
        return send_from_directory(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "static/dist"), path)

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 5000), app)
    server.serve_forever()
else:
    app = create_app()
```

This way I can navigate to http://localhost:5000 and the application will serve up the Angular app just like "ng serve" does. Now I can add in my REST API endpoints as I wanted and have Angular services access them to populate the application.

Answer (score 2):

There's no requirement that Flask serves the frontend application.

Really all Flask would be doing with an Angular app is serving static files, something that is better handled by a web server like Nginx in production, or the framework's tools like ng-serve in development.

Meanwhile, Flask would act as the backend api server that your frontend app communicates with.  Use `request.get_json()` and `return jsonify(...)` to get and respond with JSON data.

Run the two separately, they work together over HTTP only.  This also simplifies working with backend vs. frontend developers: all they need to know about is the api to communicate between the two. However, since the frontend is being served on a different port than the backend, you'll need to set up Flask appropriately to allow CORS requests, for example with Flask-CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I came across it when setting up my new project. I'm using a a more recent version of angular cli (7.3.1) and Flask (1.0.2) but the setup is pretty similar to yours. I should note that this is by no means the cleanest setup, and I'm sure the same could be achieved with webpack only, but I felt this way was a bit easier to follow (I've found webpack config can be a nightmare). My directory structure is as follows (after building):

```
client              // this is my angular project
  src
  angular.json
server              // this is my flask server
  templates
    index.html      // generated from ng build
  static
    vendor.js       // generated from ng build
    pollyfills.js
    ...
Makefile
```

In angular.json, you'll want to point the build path to your flask server:

```
  "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../server/static",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "es5BrowserSupport": true
      },
      ...
```

In my server, configure the static url:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
```

And finally in the makefile, execute the build command, and copy the template file into the templates folder:

```
all:
    cd client && ng build --prod;
    mv server/static/index.html server/templates/ ;

.PHONY : all
```

Again, not the most elegant solution but pretty straight forward to get rolling with the angular cli (rather than getting the hands dirty with webpack).

Comment: Spencer, thanks for your feedback. This is interesting to me as I'm getting back into Angular after a long while and considering re-working my personal website using it with Flask. Thanks! Doug